# IWD Onepage Checkout getItemHtml template in Magento

Tags: php, html, magento

I just would like to ask if anyone here is familiar with IWD's Onepage Checkout extension. By default, under the reviews block, it only shows the name of the product, there are no thumbnail images for each product. What I want to do is include a thumbnail in the list of products under review column.

When I tried modifying info.phtml inside /template/opc/onepage/review I found that this echoes all the products under the reviews block.

```
 <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
             <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

Now, I can't locate where is the items template that getItemHtml is calling. I tried modifying the default item.phtml under the base theme, but it didn't work.

I hope someone here is familiar with this extension and the location of the items template. :(

Comment: OOops. Never mind. I already located it inside base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OOops. Never mind. I already located it inside base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml